# Pulling out an image and displaying the image

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing code that rotates 6 pictures. All of the picture are in a div element. My main goal is whatever picture is being click on, that image shows up next to a popup box. I have created the pop up box, but I am having problems extracting the images. Any ideas? Here is how my images are coded in the body.

```
<div>
<div id="screen">
<img alt="ff" src="Pics/usb.png" onmouseover="stop()" id="usb">
<img alt="ee" src="Pics/chip.png" onmouseover="stop()" height="100" width="100"   id="chip">
<img alt="dd" src="Pics/Computer_chip.jpg" onmouseover="stop()" id="cchip">
<img alt="cc" src="Pics/alaptop.jpg" onmouseover="stop()" id="laptop">
<img alt="bb" src="Pics/cell.jpg" onmouseover="stop()" id="cell">
<img alt="aa" src="Pics/cb.jpg" onmouseover="stop()" id="cb">
</div>
</div>
```

this is the javascript I have coded

```
function loadPopup(){
//loads popup only if it is disabled
if(popupStatus==0){
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "opacity": "0.0"
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#screen").css({
        "opacity": "0.0"            
    });
    $("#screen img").css({
        "position": "absolute"

        });


    popupStatus = 1;

}
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup(){
//disables popup only if it is enabled
if(popupStatus==1){
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");

    popupStatus = 0;
    $("#screen").css({
        "opacity": "1"
    });
}
}

//centering popup
function posPopup(){
//request data for centering
var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
//centering
$("#popupContact").css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": windowHeight/9-popupHeight/8,
    "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/8
});
$("#usb1").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/8,
    "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/8
});
//only need force for IE6


$("#backgroundPopup").css({
    "height": windowHeight
});

}


//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

//LOADING POPUP
//Click the image event!
$("#usb").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    posPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
    stop();

});
$("#chip").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    posPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
    stop();

});
$("#cchip").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    posPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
    stop();

});
$("#laptop").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    posPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
    stop();

});
$("#cell").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    posPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
    stop();

});
$("#cb").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    posPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
    stop();

});

//CLOSING POPUP
//Click the x event!
$("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
    disablePopup();
    m.run();
});
//Click out event!
$("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
    disablePopup();
    m.run();
});
//Press Escape event!
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
        disablePopup();
        m.run();
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
$("#images img").click(function() {
    var img = $(this).clone();
    $('#target img').remove(); 
    $('#target').html(img);     
});​
```

This code is cloning the image you are clicking on and writing it to target div.

This is working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldfq2/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the Javascript you are using to do this?  Basically you would give at least the target `<img` an `id` and change it `src` attribute in response to a click event.

Comment: something I tried doing was to put the image i am trying to grab in another div. so other than the div that has the 6 rotating images, i created another div that hold just one pic. the weird this is i can get this to work to some extent. i created a css class an invoked it on the div element that has the one pic, and kind of works. when i have the image displayed on the screen and click on one of the rotating images, the image moves. but when i have the display set to none, and click the image, the image does not appear. all this is done in the css class i created